# Are multiple variations of a question with subtle distinctions duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

We now have three questions about *Star Trek's* Captain Kirk's romantic conquests.

1. The [original question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15336/with-how-many-women-did-kirk-have-an-affair?rq=1) seems to have been restricted to just the original TV series.  It made no restriction on whether the conquests were human or alien.
2. A [more recent question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32051/how-many-alien-women-has-capt-admiral-kirk-slept-with#comment60845_32051) asked specifically about *only* alien women, and included movies.
3. This spawned [yet another version](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32057/how-many-females-has-captain-kirk-slept-with) that looks for total women (alien and human), and is not limited to the TV show (books are clearly acceptable, but there is no mention of movies).

Are these all distinct enough to stand on their own, or should some (or all three) be linked as duplicates?

Comment: So how do we action this/

Comment: I *think* it's all straightened out now.  Flag it if I missed something.

Comment: @Keen It looks perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I think the ideal situation is to have a single, comprehensive question that covers all the variations.  An ideal answer would be something along the lines of:

> There were 36 total romantic affairs, three of which took place in the movies (2 in the same movie!), 18 in the original TV series, one in ST:TNG (!), and 14 in various novels.  The list is as follows (aliens are denoted with a *):

To that end, I propose that [Kevin Howell's version of the question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32051/how-many-alien-women-has-capt-admiral-kirk-slept-with) be edited (with his approval, of course) to read:

### How many women has Captain Kirk slept with?

It's an on going punchline that Kirk banged his way across the galaxy.

Is it actually based on fact though? In the TV series and movies, how many actual women did Kirk boldly go into with his Enterprise? (pun intended).  Please distinguish aliens from humans, for those who are curious, and also indicate which are from the TV series and which are from movies.

The only woman I know for sure he Zap Brannigen'd was the lady who had his son.

---

Normally, I would suggest that the first question be kept, but since the OP of that question has disassociated/deleted their account, I think it appropriate to keep the reputation gains for our currently active members.

I'm not certain whether novels should be included in that list or not; DVK's answer seems to have a pretty good source on instances within the novels, so maybe they should.

Comment: So do you propose I re-post my asnwer from #3 back into #2 and asterisk the aliens? Just making sure I got your proposal correctly.

Comment: @DVK Yes, I believe that would be ideal, although I would suggest that your answer on #3 be deleted (it seems a bit... off... to have the same answer on multiple questions, including one of your own; I'm sure you'll get enough upvotes in the other question to make up for what you'll lose).

Comment: Yes, makes sense

Comment: Definitely recommend against including novels in this question. Might be reasonable to have a separate question just for that. Typically though, when you add the novels into the scope of a Star Trek list question, those sorts of question catch abuse for being too broadly scoped.

Comment: I agree with this completely. I did try to search for my question before I posted ( I always like to do that) and didn't find anything. I would never have thought of affair as the same as slept with since affair usually means you are married. In my opinion the better and more complete the question and the answer the better for the site in general. A bunch of off shoot "well what about this instance" type questions just diverts the intention of stackexchange. Also I think an answer that lists the novels would be good but I try not to ask about novels since that usually starts a new cannon.

Comment: I deleted my answer on #3. People don't seem to be in any great hurry to close #1 or #3 though.

Comment: #2 got closed; I voted to reopen.  I also made the edits discussed. If we can get it reopened, we can close question #1

Answer (score 0):

IMHO:

- The spawned-off [question #3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32057/how-many-females-has-captain-kirk-slept-with) asked by me should be closed as duplicate. I VTCed it myself and flagged for mods to merge (so my answer isn't lost). I checked that there were no dupes but somehow missed the original one.

  <sub>In a more self-serving version, question #1 should be closed as a duplicate of #3, since #3 seems to be of a higher quality - it very clearly explains what is and isn't counted as opposed to generic may-be-courtship-with-no-sex-is-included "affairs"; and has a more complete and correct answer than either of the answers to #1. But I can easily repost my answer on #1 so I don't care much either way.</sub>
- The more recent "alien" [question #2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32051/how-many-alien-women-has-capt-admiral-kirk-slept-with#comment60845_32051) **should stand on its own**.

  - The question itself, as noted, is specifically asking for "alien" ones.
  - Moreover, NONE of the answers (two answers from Q#1, or my new more complete answer to Q#3) make any human/alien distinctions.

    Therefore, the MAIN reason for "duplicate" closing (that is, the answers to another question also answer this one) is not present in this case.

Comment: As a side note: TV/movie/books scope is also a factor to keep #2 by itself, but not nearly as important IMHO.